# How to set horizontal lines in Edit Text xml in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

am trying to get horizontal lines in editText in Android notepad application. Everything is fine but I am getting error when I click on add note error.

In Graphic layout it is showing horizontal lines but not working when I am calling it on Emulator. Please suggest.

```
06-25 11:52:07.980: D/gralloc_goldfish(2235): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-25 11:52:11.178: D/AndroidRuntime(2235): Shutting down VM
06-25 11:52:11.178: W/dalvikvm(2235): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sassypuma.todo.task/com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task.LinedEditText
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task.LinedEditText
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task.onCreate(Add_Task.java:19)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     ... 11 more
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.Add_Task.LinedEditText
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
06-25 11:52:11.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2235):     ... 20 more
```

Add Note Activity:

```
 public class Add_Task extends Activity{

private EditText description;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);
    description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);
}
```

}

Lined Edit Text Class:

```
 class LinedEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

// we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public void init(){
        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF668800); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //int count = getLineCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

EDITED:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.LinedEditText
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:gravity="top"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:lines="12"
android:capitalize="sentences" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please share your layout xml file.. what is the package for `LinedEditText.java`?

Comment: Remove the namespace declaration from LinedEditText.

Comment: Still not working error in line:   <com.android.sassypuma.todo.task.LinedEditText

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just close your Eclipse with layout opened. Start it again. This will refresh its links to custom class.